# Java code doesn't run when subtracting from an int

Tags: java

```
    for (i=1; i < 9; i++) {
        for (j=1; j < 9; j++) {
            if ( board[i][j] == "o" ) {
                j = j-1;

                if ( board[i][j] == "x" ) {
                    do {
                        j--;
                    }
                    while (board[i][j] != "-");
                    board[i][j] = ".";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have this piece of code as part of a method, there are two versions, one as written above and one where j = j-1 is replaced with j = j+1 and j-- is replaced with j++

The positive version works perfectly fine but if I put in the negative version, the code compiles fine but when I attempt to run it nothing happens, the console just hangs and I have to close and reopen it. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

edit:

```
for (i=1; i < 9; i++) {
        for (j=1; j < 9; j++) {
            if ( board[i][j].equals("o") ) {
                j = j-1;

                if ( board[i][j].equals("x") ) {
                    do {
                        j--;
                    }
                    while (!board[i][j].equals("-"));
                    board[i][j] = ".";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have edited the code as indicated but the problem persists

Comment: @tunaki I'm not sure how this is a duplicate of the post you indicated?

Comment: Look at this again `if ( board[i][j] == "o" )`

Comment: but this part works perfectly fine when i have j = j+1, why should it stop working when i say j=j-1?

Comment: @Tunaki I'm not having trouble comparing anything, the problem arises when I try to set my integer j to j-1

Comment: Your code as-is is incorrect. And this is probably related to comparing Strings. You need to fix this and debug.

Comment: @Tunaki I edited the code as the other post recommended but my problem persists

Comment: You also have a trailing `;` here `while (!board[i][j].equals("-"));`. I suggest you restart and try to make a [mcve]. Please read [ask].

Comment: You also never check board[0][0] is that intentional? Arrays are zero indexed

Comment: @Tunaki - do while loops have trailing semi colons

Comment: @Tunaki That trailing `;` is part of a do/while. It isn't incorrect.

Comment: And changing the loop variable within the loop doesn't seem like a good idea...

Comment: @cricket_007 yes it's intentional, the first row and column are just numbered coordinates, so I don't want to check them

Comment: @EJP Why was this posted reopened? It is still obviously missing a [mcve]! We still have no idea what the problem is after 10 comments at least.

Comment: If the console is "hanging" that most likely (almost certainly) means you have created an infinite loop. Have you tried stepping through in a step by step debugger (as will be provided in any good IDE) to examine the code flow

Comment: I guess the fact that your program hangs has something to do with `j = j - 1` and the `j++` in your `for`-loop. You should avoid modifying the `for` loop counter variable (`i` and `j`), unless you absolutely have to or know what you're doing.

Comment: @Tunaki Because it isn't a duplicate of what it was closed as? At least three of those comments are about an irrelevance.

Comment: @EJP So you want to close it again as "No MCVE"?

Comment: @Tunaki I don't want to close it at all. Why are you asking me?

Comment: Thanks cricket_007 MCEmperor and RichardTingle this was the problem, very silly mistake on my part thanks for the help

Comment: Resolved in a manner not to be useful to future readers (allegedly). Wanna just delete it? That is, only if *you* want to

Comment: @Drew , If you're asking me, I have no issue with it being deleted if it won't be useful to future readers.

Comment: I am not the judge on that. You choose. Maybe those that follow will get something out of it. Thanks.

Comment: @Drew Either you are suggesting this is not useful or you aren't. Make up your mind.

Comment: @EJP I just answered that. Once it hits 2 answers, deleting is more difficult.

Comment: @Drew I can't see any harm in leaving it on the off chance that someone makes the same mistake as I did.

Comment: @Drew So who is doing the alleging here? Can't see anyone else doing it.

Comment: Back to what we were doing

Comment: @Drew Please clarify your comments as requested. Or delete them. They appear to be quite devoid of meaning to me.

Comment: @EJP There is a close reason for Typo, or resolved in a manner unlikely to be useful to future readers. If people want to close or leave open, fine with me. I was alerting the OP of the options. Thanks. Now I *do* have to split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong. You're never changing the square that contains "x", so you keep encountering it, so you keep decrementing `j,` so you will encounter it again next time, so ...

Comment: you're right I was attempting to find the space next to the one with the "x" but didn't realise i was creating the infinite loop by using the same variables in my a for loop and my while loop. Thanks